# Catching a 'rosnode kill -a'

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bit of code that outputs data when the core dies. This works fine in all situations, except when the user uses 'rosnode kill -a'. The PR2 runs this command when stopping the robot, so it's a larger issue with specific robots than with ROS itself.

I believe this particular command is running a SIGKILL on all ROS nodes. These cannot be caught. Is there some other signal ROS sends out right before it dies that I can take advantage of?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240671/catching-a-%27rosnode-kill--a%27/) by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 211 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think `rosnode kill` is sending SIGKILL. (If it is, there's nothing you can do).

I'm reasonably certain that `rosnode kill` uses the node's XMLRPC API to request that the node shutdown cleanly; in C++ you can check for this with `ros::ok()` or `ros::isShuttingDown()`, as described on the [roscpp initialization and shutdown page](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0